# How to use rowiterator in apache poi?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm looking for a way to create .xlsx file for reporting from database. The problem is that  data are being overwritten when I try to return back to the first row of the file. Did anyone have the same problem with apache poi? I would like to create three tables in the same level. I have found a solution for the problem by creating all the tables at the same time row by row but it takes a lot of time as I have many loops in my code. I have also tried to use getRow(i) but it didn't help anymore. I need some help please.

[image: I have created my .xlsx file like below]

AND This is part of code I went to optimize by getting first row:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 1, k = 2; k <= utilisateurs.size(); i = i + 3, j = j + 3, k = k + 3) {
        Utilisateur u1 = null;
        Utilisateur u2 = null;
        Utilisateur u3 = null;
        int totaleU1 = 0;
        int totaleU2 = 0;
        int totaleU3 = 0;
        List<SyntheseCandidatDto> listeU1;
        List<SyntheseCandidatDto> listeU2;
        List<SyntheseCandidatDto> listeU3;
        if (utilisateurs.size() - i >= 3) {
            u1 = utilisateurs.get(i);
            u2 = utilisateurs.get(j);
            u3 = utilisateurs.get(k);
        } else if (utilisateurs.size() - i == 2) {
            u1 = utilisateurs.get(i);
            u2 = utilisateurs.get(j);
        } else if (utilisateurs.size() - i == 1) {
            u1 = utilisateurs.get(i);
        }
        Row hderRow;
        Cell hdrCell;
        Cell nomSourceurCell;
        hderRow = sh.createRow(rowNum++);
        if (u1 != null) {
            hdrCell = hderRow.createCell(0);
            hdrCell.setCellValue("Sourceur: ");
            hdrCell.setCellStyle(sousTitre);
            nomSourceurCell = hderRow.createCell(1);
            nomSourceurCell.setCellValue(utilisateurs.get(i).getNom() + " "
                    + utilisateurs.get(i).getPrenom());
            nomSourceurCell.setCellStyle(csNomSrc);
            sh.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(rowNum - 1, rowNum - 1,
                    1, 2));
        }
        if (u2 != null) {
            Cell cell = hderRow.createCell(technologies.size() + 2);
            cell.setCellValue("Sourceur: ");
            cell.setCellStyle(sousTitre);
            nomSourceurCell = hderRow.createCell(technologies.size() + 3);
            nomSourceurCell
                    .setCellValue(u2.getNom() + " " + u2.getPrenom());
            nomSourceurCell.setCellStyle(csNomSrc);
            sh.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(rowNum - 1, rowNum - 1,
                    technologies.size() + 3, technologies.size() + 4));
        }
        if (u3 != null) {
            Cell cellSrc = hderRow.createCell(2 * technologies.size() + 3);
            cellSrc.setCellValue("Sourceur: ");
            cellSrc.setCellStyle(sousTitre);
            nomSourceurCell = hderRow
                    .createCell(2 * technologies.size() + 4);
            nomSourceurCell
                    .setCellValue(u3.getNom() + " " + u3.getPrenom());
            nomSourceurCell.setCellStyle(csNomSrc);
            sh.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(rowNum - 1, rowNum - 1,
                    2 * technologies.size() + 4,
                    2 * technologies.size() + 5));
        }
        if (u1 != null) {
            Row technoRow = sh.createRow(rowNum++);
            Cell technoCell;
            for (int l = 0; l < technologies.size(); l++) {
                if (u1 != null) {
                    technoCell = technoRow.createCell(l + 1);
                    technoCell.setCellValue(technologies.get(l)
                            .getLibelle());
                    technoCell.setCellStyle(csCellTechno);
                    sh.setColumnWidth(technoCell.getColumnIndex(),
                            (short) (50 * 80));
                }
                if (u2 != null) {
                    technoCell = technoRow.createCell(l
                            + technologies.size() + 2);
                    technoCell.setCellValue(technologies.get(l)
                            .getLibelle());
                    technoCell.setCellStyle(csCellTechno);
                    sh.setColumnWidth(technoCell.getColumnIndex(),
                            (short) (50 * 80));
                }
                if (u3 != null) {
                    technoCell = technoRow.createCell(l + 2
                            * technologies.size() + 3);
                    technoCell.setCellValue(technologies.get(l)
                            .getLibelle());
                    technoCell.setCellStyle(csCellTechno);
                    sh.setColumnWidth(technoCell.getColumnIndex(),
                            (short) (50 * 80));
                }
            }
        }
        long val = 0;
        Row villeRow;
        for (int m = 0; m < regions.size(); m++) {
            villeRow = sh.createRow(rowNum++);
            Cell cellVille;
            cellVille = villeRow.createCell(0);
            cellVille.setCellValue(regions.get(m).getCode());
            cellVille.setCellStyle(csCellVille);
            sh.setColumnWidth(cellVille.getColumnIndex(),
                    (short) (50 * 150));
            Cell cellTechno;
            if (u1 != null) {

                listeU1 = map.get(u1);
                for (int l = 0; l < technologies.size(); l++) {
                    Boolean foundU1 = false;
                    int sommeRegionU1 = 0;

                    Boolean foundU2 = false;
                    int sommeRegionU2 = 0;

                    Boolean foundU3 = false;
                    int sommeRegionU3 = 0;
                    for (SyntheseCandidatDto candidatDtoU1 : listeU1) {
                        if (candidatDtoU1.getRegion().equals(
                                regions.get(m).getCode())
                                && candidatDtoU1
                                        .getTechnologie()
                                        .getLibelle()
                                        .equals(technologies.get(l)
                                                .getLibelle())) {
                            sommeRegionU1 += candidatDtoU1
                                    .getTotalCandidat();
                            foundU1 = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (u2 != null) {
                        listeU2 = map.get(u2);
                        for (SyntheseCandidatDto candidatDtoU2 : listeU2) {
                            if (candidatDtoU2.getRegion().equals(
                                    regions.get(m).getCode())
                                    && candidatDtoU2
                                            .getTechnologie()
                                            .getLibelle()
                                            .equals(technologies.get(l)
                                                    .getLibelle())) {
                                sommeRegionU2 += candidatDtoU2
                                        .getTotalCandidat();
                                foundU2 = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (u3 != null) {
                            listeU3 = map.get(u3);
                            for (SyntheseCandidatDto candidatDtoU3 : listeU3) {
                                if (candidatDtoU3.getRegion().equals(
                                        regions.get(m).getCode())
                                        && candidatDtoU3
                                                .getTechnologie()
                                                .getLibelle()
                                                .equals(technologies.get(l)
                                                        .getLibelle())) {
                                    val = candidatDtoU3.getTotalCandidat();
                                    sommeRegionU3 += candidatDtoU3
                                            .getTotalCandidat();
                                    foundU3 = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (foundU1) {
                            cellTechno = villeRow.createCell(l + 1);
                            cellTechno.setCellValue(sommeRegionU1 + "");
                            cellTechno.setCellStyle(csCellNumber);
                        } else {
                            cellTechno = villeRow.createCell(l + 1);
                            cellTechno.setCellValue("-");
                            cellTechno.setCellStyle(csCellNumber);
                        }

                        if (u2 != null) {
                            if (foundU2) {
                                cellTechno = villeRow.createCell(l
                                        + technologies.size() + 2);
                                cellTechno.setCellValue(sommeRegionU2 + "");
                                cellTechno.setCellStyle(csCellNumber);
                            } else {
                                cellTechno = villeRow.createCell(l
                                        + technologies.size() + 2);
                                cellTechno.setCellValue("-");
                                cellTechno.setCellStyle(csCellNumber);
                            }
                        }

                        if (u3 != null) {
                            if (foundU3) {
                                cellTechno = villeRow.createCell(l + 2
                                        * technologies.size() + 3);
                                cellTechno.setCellValue(sommeRegionU3 + "");
                                cellTechno.setCellStyle(csCellNumber);
                            } else {
                                cellTechno = villeRow.createCell(l + 2
                                        * technologies.size() + 3);
                                cellTechno.setCellValue("-");
                                cellTechno.setCellStyle(csCellNumber);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (u1 != null) {
            listeU1 = map.get(u1);
            Row totRow = sh.createRow(rowNum++);
            Cell totCell;
            Cell cellHdrVill1;
            sh.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(rowNum - 1, rowNum, 0,
                    0));
            cellHdrVill1 = totRow.createCell(0);
            cellHdrVill1.setCellValue("Total");
            cellHdrVill1.setCellStyle(csCellTot);

            for (int l = 0; l < technologies.size(); l++) {
                int sumtechU1 = 0;
                int sumtechU2 = 0;
                int sumtechU3 = 0;
                for (SyntheseCandidatDto syntheseCandidatDto : listeU1) {
                    if (syntheseCandidatDto.getTechnologie().equals(
                            technologies.get(l))) {
                        sumtechU1 += syntheseCandidatDto.getTotalCandidat();
                    }
                }
                totCell = totRow.createCell(l + 1);
                totCell.setCellValue(sumtechU1);
                totCell.setCellStyle(csCellTot);

                if (u2 != null) {
                    listeU2 = map.get(u2);
                    for (SyntheseCandidatDto syntheseCandidatDto : listeU2) {

                        if (syntheseCandidatDto.getTechnologie().equals(
                                technologies.get(l))) {
                            sumtechU2 += syntheseCandidatDto
                                    .getTotalCandidat();

                        }
                    }
                    totCell = totRow
                            .createCell(l + technologies.size() + 2);
                    totCell.setCellValue(sumtechU2);
                    totCell.setCellStyle(csCellTot);

                }
                if (u3 != null) {
                    listeU3 = map.get(u3);
                    for (SyntheseCandidatDto syntheseCandidatDto : listeU3) {

                        if (syntheseCandidatDto.getTechnologie().equals(
                                technologies.get(l))) {
                            sumtechU3 += syntheseCandidatDto
                                    .getTotalCandidat();
                        }
                    }
                    totCell = totRow.createCell(l + 2 * technologies.size()
                            + 3);
                    totCell.setCellValue(sumtechU3);
                    totCell.setCellStyle(csCellTot);
                }
                totaleU1 += sumtechU1;
                totaleU2 += sumtechU2;
                totaleU3 += sumtechU3;
            }
        }
        Row totUserRow = sh.createRow(rowNum++);
        Cell totCell = totUserRow.createCell(0);
        totCell.setCellValue("");

        totCell.setCellStyle(csCellTot);
        Cell totCellValue = totUserRow.createCell(1);
        totCellValue.setCellValue(totaleU1);
        totCellValue.setCellStyle(csCellTot);

        totCell = totUserRow.createCell(technologies.size() + 2);
        totCell.setCellValue(totaleU2);
        totCell.setCellStyle(csCellTot);

        totCellValue = totUserRow.createCell(2 * technologies.size() + 3);
        totCellValue.setCellValue(totaleU3);
        totCellValue.setCellStyle(csCellTot);
        rowNum++;
    }
```

Comment: I have no desire to rewrite your entire code but hint: [org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellUtil](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellUtil.html) seems to be what you need. There are methods `getRow` and `getCell` which will either create rows or cells or simply get them if they exists already.

Comment: Think you Axel. Finally, I got the solution by creating the three tables at the same time line by line and it works so well ;)

Answer (score 0):

What's about: create/edit rows begin 0 for each table, and just the cell index accumulated; then you just need 3 'for' loops for 3 tables;

Steps need to complete the work:
1. get the row, by function getRow;
2. check the row, if null, create row by createRow function;

Comment: I have many tables not only three! When on row is created and rowIndex is incremented it can't be reset, later, to earlier index! That is the source of the problem.

Comment: When I create 1st row and put 1st line of the 1st Table, I can't set rowIndex later in the 1st line of 2nd table! The cellIndex is set correctly, but rowIndex no.

Comment: As Axel recommended, should use getRow function to write table 2/3/... to the same row of sheet;

Comment: When I have tried this solution 1st table is being removed by 2nd table, it is like exclusive access so that each line uses an entire row of the file.

Comment: What I'm trying to do now is to create the three tables at the same time line by line.

Comment: I tried from my project; It works by getRow to write the second table without first table removed;